# How to match this regex or null?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript function that validates user input shown below:

```
function validateRugSize(rug_size) {
    var regex = /^(\d{1,2})(\')? (\d{1,2})("|\'\')? (x|X)? ?(\d{1,2})(\')? (\d{1,2})("|\'\')?$/;
    return regex.test(rug_size);
}
```

which gets called here:

```
if (!validateRugSize(rug_size[i])) {
    $("#SizeLabel" + i).text("Please enter a valid Rug Size.");
    $("#SizeLabel" + i).css("color", "red");
    $("#Size" + i).focus();
    return false;
} else {
    $("#SizeLabel" + i).text("");
}
```

I want the user's input to be valided only if a user enters a value there.  I don't want to require input, however.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an extra condition:

```
if((rug_size[i].length > 0){
    if (!validateRugSize(rug_size[i])) {
        $("#SizeLabel" + i).text("Please enter a valid Rug Size.");
        $("#SizeLabel" + i).css("color", "red");
        $("#Size" + i).focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#SizeLabel" + i).text("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep.  I realized it just after I posted.  I'll give credit soon.

Comment: You're fast, @Adrian B!